# How to determine eod

Tags: bash, shell, dd, mt

I would like to read various partitions from a DDS tape using a script
At the moment I am using the following script

```
TAPE=/dev/nst0         
BLOCK_SIZE=32768        
COUNTER=1
END_OF_DATA=120

while [  $COUNTER -lt $END_OF_DATA ] 
do      
       dd if=$TAPE bs=$BLOCK_SIZE of=file_$COUNTER  
       let COUNTER+=1 
done
```

However, as you can see my script can read at maximum 120 partitions.

How can I modify this code to enable the script to recognise the end of data of the tape automatically

Thanks

Comment: I'm not proficient in that domain, but can someone explain how/why `dd` stops reading at the end of the partition in the above script ?

Comment: Much easier than that. I need only to know when my tape gets the end of data. For instance something like this: `if[COUNTER=eod]then exit fi`

Comment: @SylvainLeroux the reason is because it is partitioned and the dd stops at the end of each partition. This is the reason I put the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep comparing the report with block size. And yes you have to open the device only once and keep reading from it.

```
TAPE=/dev/nst0 
BLOCK_SIZE=32768
COUNTER=1

while [ "$(dd bs="$BLOCK_SIZE" of="file_$COUNTER" 2>&1 count=1 | awk '/bytes/ { print $1 }')" -eq "$BLOCK_SIZE" ]; do
    let ++COUNTER
done < "$TAPE"
```

Script is tested with a file.

You can also remove the last file if last number of bytes read was just 0:

```
while
    BYTES_READ=$(dd bs="$BLOCK_SIZE" of="file_$COUNTER" 2>&1 count=1 | awk '/bytes/ { print $1 }')
    [ "$BYTES_READ" -eq "$BLOCK_SIZE" ]
do
    let ++COUNTER
done < "$TAPE"

[ "$BYTES_READ" -eq 0 ] && rm -f "file_$COUNTER"
```

If you want to send a message while you process the tape, you can use redirections and use another file descriptor for it:

```
TAPE=temp
BLOCK_SIZE=32768
COUNTER=1

while
    FILE="file_$COUNTER"
    echo "Reading $BLOCK_SIZE from $TAPE and writing it to file $FILE."
    BYTES_READ=$(dd bs="$BLOCK_SIZE" of="$FILE" count=1 2>&1 <&4 | awk '/bytes/ { print $1 }')
    echo "$BYTES_READ bytes read."
    [ "$BYTES_READ" -eq "$BLOCK_SIZE" ]
do
    let ++COUNTER
done 4< "$TAPE"

[ "$BYTES_READ" -eq 0 ] && rm -f "$FILE"
```

Example output:

```
Reading 32768 from temp and writing it to file file_1.
32768 bytes read.
Reading 32768 from temp and writing it to file file_2.
32768 bytes read.
Reading 32768 from temp and writing it to file file_3.
32768 bytes read.
Reading 32768 from temp and writing it to file file_4.
32768 bytes read.
Reading 32768 from temp and writing it to file file_5.
32268 bytes read.
```

Another option is to just send your `echo`s to `/dev/stderr`.

```
echo "Reading $BLOCK_SIZE from $TAPE and writing it to file $FILE." >&2
```

To make it a little faster also, use `exec` inside the subshell to prevent extra fork:

```
BYTES_READ=$(exec dd ...)
```

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino Probably no with respect to the function of `dd` but the script's being naturally slower than a native application can be questioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works very well!! However, it does not seem to be as much quick as the original one

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino Well with the original one you don't seem to exactly divide the input as you seem to keep on reading it from the start on every loop that every file you make would just give same content.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, I'm not very proficient with this issue, but as *"`dd` stops at the end of each partition"*, why don't you simply read until there is nothing more to read?

```
TAPE=/dev/nst0         
BLOCK_SIZE=32768        
COUNTER=1

while true 
do      
       dd if=$TAPE bs=$BLOCK_SIZE of=file_$COUNTER

       if [ \! -s file_$COUNTER ]
       then
               # clean-up empty file and exit the loop
               rm file_$COUNTER
               break
       fi
       let COUNTER+=1 
done
```

*(untested)*

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino Don't miss the last word: _"(untested)"_ -- let me know _if_ this works ;) .